# Problema con axios vue y php: Undefined Index

Tags: php, javascript, html, vue.js, axios

Tengo un código muy simple, estoy utilizando VueJs PHP y axios para peticiones Ajax

Tengo un botón que envía por ajax datos a un archivo php por post pero este no reconoce datos post, eso infiero a partir de este error:

> Notice: Undefined index: email in
>   /opt/lampp/htdocs/proyectos/winecommunity/php/index.php on line 2

El HTML

```
<button @click="sendEmail">Enviar </button>
<p> {{{res}}} </p>

<script src="js/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/axios/dist/axios.min.js"></script>

<script src="js/index.js"></script>
```

EL php

```
echo $_POST['email'];
```

y el js

```
new Vue({
    el: 'body',
    data: {
        email:'emipmttt@gmail.com',
        res:'tu email'
    },
    methods: {
        sendEmail: function (){
            var vm = this;
            axios.post('php/index.php', {
                email:vm.email,
            })
            .then(function (response) {
                vm.res = response.data
            })
            .catch(function (error) {
            console.log(error);
            });
        }
    }

})
```

Alguna idea de qué necesito para que php me regrese el email?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En primer lugar para su código, se recomienda que el elemento `root` no sea el tag `<body>`, incluso lanza error en consola si es así, por lo cuál debe envolver el contenido en un elemento raíz o padre.

Luego para imprimir los valores se utilizan las dobles llaves y no 3 `{{ valor }}`

Para que funcione el envió de datos, deberá añadirlos a un  `FormData`, recomendaría tener todos los datos que serán modificados o `v-model` en un objeto padre *(postData  para el ejemplo)* para luego generar el envío.

**HTML**

```
<div id="app">
    <button @click="sendEmail">Enviar </button>
    <p> {{res}} </p>
</div>
```

**VUEJs**

```
new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: {
          //Objeto postData, se pueden añadir más propiedades
        postData :  {email:'emipmttt@gmail.com'},
        res:'tu email'
    },
    methods: {
        sendEmail: function (){
            var vm = this;
            axios.post('php/index.php',this.createdFormData())
            .then(function (response) {
                vm.res = response.data
            })
            .catch(function (error) {
                console.log(error);
            });
        },
        // función para generar el formData a partir del objeto postData
         createdFormData : function (){
                    var formDa = new FormData();
                for(var key in this.postData){
                    formDa.append(key, this.postData[key]);
                }
                return formDa;
            }
    }
})
```

Comment: Funciona te agradezco Jodel. En vue las triples llaves sirven para renderizar html, si utilizara dobles llaves el resultado del error que aparecía sería el siguiente: <br /> <b>Notice</b>: Undefined index: email in <b>/opt/lampp/htdocs/proyectos/winecommunity/php/index.php</b> on line <b>2</b><br />